# Express Router with a sub-router

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Let's say parent module has a router with public requests using

**Parent Module**

```
app.get("/speakers",...
app.get("/agenda",... etc.
```

and another wild card route which actually delegates the request to child module to handle all of it's nested operations which parent module doesn't need to know or care about.

```
app.all("/admin/*/*" //delegates task to another module
```

**Child Module**

child module receives the admin request but then it has to deal with all uri's, routes and params

like

```
/admin/login
/admin/dashboard/events
/admin/dashboard/events/1 //could go deeper
```

How to have another level of route parsing or engine at this nested level?

Comment: You could use [`express.Router`](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html#express-router), add routes to the router and then `app.use("/admin", theRouter)`

Comment: sorry it's not clear, I'm shuttling `request` and `response` to child module which have it's own scope and has no knowledge about the `parent` or `app`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can organize your admin routes as a separate module like this:

**/routes/admin.js**

```
var login = function(req, res, next) {
    res.end();
}

// etc...

module.exports = express.Router()
    .post('/login', login)
    .get('/dashboard/events', listEvents)
    .get('/dashboard/events/:id', findEvent);
```

Then in your **app.js**:

```
var admin = require('./routes/admin');
app.use('/admin', admin);
```

Note that the routes you defined in the admin route are all going to be relative to the root you specified as the first param to `app.use`.

Comment: so that means the app (parent) has to know about all the admin routes because in app.js I've to write 'var admin = require('./routes/admin');' so no separation of concerns or decoupling, where as I want the app not to know anything except it's for `/admin/*.*/*` module and let child module take care of the rest, I'm trying to apply some design patterns and software engineering principles here

Comment: No the app does NOT need to know about the admin routes, only your admin module knows... `./routes/admin` is just the path to your admin module... not to be confused with your service route. Define your module in `/potato/blap.js` if you wish, in which case you would  `require('./potato/blap')` in app.js.

Comment: your answer refined and expanded upon my architecture, which is very different but I got connecting pieces out of it and solved the puzzle, thanks. I basically shuttled app and express to the child module (not exactly a commonJS module but I'd say child core or child app), where they define all admin level routes.

Comment: basically app only, express module is not required at that level

Comment: Please comment on this approach, I'd like to hear any critique for passing app variable to sub modules (cores) if they have their own set of routes, without defining at the parent level

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really the forum for this kind of question, but https://programmers.stackexchange.com is. If you post your question there I'd be curious to see what people say. Personally I don't like the idea of shuttling app to submodules because it introduces an unnecessary coupling and opens the door to having two submodules do conflicting things to the shared app var. But like I said, this chat medium is a terrible way to discuss this topic, if you want to continue this discussion please do it on programmers.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for the suggestion, I'm going to open up this discussion, your point is valid since conflict can arise, but I'm enforcing to have the submodule to specify `/admin/...` calls only, no top level requests, I'm enforcing it at my end and can communicate to the team, that's the only way I can think of to get a new slate for all submodule related tasks, and hence freeing up parent module to delegate for submodule concerns which it doesn't want to bother about.